# How do I get my island beetles back?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Playing Animal Crossing: New Leaf, my 6-year-old daughter has carried out an extensive deforestation project on Tortimer's Island. This is unfortunate, because those coconut trees would regularly attract huge beetles worth a pretty bell.

How can I go about repopulating the island with lucrative beetles?

Comment: More of a side question to this one:  Is it possible to transfer/trade Island Fruit between players?  I would assume that would be the best way to restore the trees there.

Answer (score 5):

If you go on a tour, you can take items from the Tour back to the Island. You need to go on a tour that allows access to the beach, like the hide and seek tour. You can grab the bananas and coconuts from the game and bring it back to the island to re-plant.

Answer (score 0):

You have to either have Coconuts or Bananas to get them back, because the Island beetles only come on the Tropical trees. To get them:

- Go on the tropical fishing tour, or any other tour that has Coconuts or Bananas.
- Exchange friend codes with people and visit their town; you can ask if they have any of the following fruits.

Once you have acquired either of those fruits, plant them on your Island on the sandy terrain. They will fully grow within 3 days. Once they are fully grown, the Island Bugs will appear from 5 PM to 8 AM. 
Hope I helped!

Comment: I don't understand the friend code visiting thing. Normally going to the island doesn't let you bring anything along, so why would it help to bring friends?